# How to manage a queue with timer and with some conditions in NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, sockets, express, events

I am creating a **Taxi App**, In which, when user order a taxi, three nearby driver are selected by system, and it sends a request to first driver.

Now driver will have 30sec to accept or decline the booking, if driver accepts then booking is confirmed and no other driver will be notified,

But if driver decline booking or didn't respond to the booking in 30 sec, a request will be send to second driver.

**Now the problem is that, I don't know how to manage a action queue in which there are three conditions.**

1. If system don't get a reply from first driver in 30 sec, send
   request to next driver in queue
2. If driver accept the booking the  stop the queue process and book a
       ride.
3. If driver decline the booking, then instantly send request to next
           driver without waiting for 30sec period.

   Any suggestion and Ideas are welcome.

Comment: Can you show any code please? it seems you can use promises with some setTimeouts, but I would like to see some code

Comment: Not sure how this got so many upvotes considering this is a not so great question for the StackOverflow format, please read [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: @peteb I've stopped wondering about that, even _really_ bad questions get upvotes, more so recently than before.

Comment: peteb @robertklep sorry for a bad question quality, but I don't have a exact code to put in the question, Can you please give any idea or suggestion at least to solve my problem

Comment: @PuneetSingh what have you tried so far?

Comment: @robertklep I have created a express server with socket.io in it, so driver and client app can send data to each other through server, client emit book_taxi on that listner server search 3 online driver from mongodb and emit a new_booking event to first driver socket. 

After that I am confused, what to do for scenario mentioned in question.

Comment: @PuneetSingh you have described three steps. Start by implementing the first and work your way through the rest sequentially.